# PivotTable generation from selected range

Tags: vba, excel, pivot-table

Having trouble defining the source for a pivot table. What I need to do is define the source data for the pivot table via selection, because there won’t be a static table name or static cell range to identify in the code.

The selection that I will be using is after a table has been pasted so the selection will be of the entire table; the same range as if you defined it in the commented out line (in the code below) that works.

The code below results in a run time error.

I'm real new and learning lots. Thanks for the help and patience.

```
Sub CreatePivotTable()
'Creates a brand new Pivot table on a new worksheet from data in the ActiveSheet

Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim pvtCache As PivotCache
Dim pvt As PivotTable
Dim StartPvt As String
Dim SrcData As String

'Determine the data range you want to pivot via selection

   Dim E As Range
   Set E = Selection
   SrcData = E.Address(ReferenceStyle:=xlR1C1)

  'This piece of code below substituted for the 3 lines above works?
  'SrcData = ActiveSheet.Name & "!" & Range("A3:H7").Address(ReferenceStyle:=xlR1C1)

'Select worksheet
  Set sht = Sheets("Sheet2")
    Sheets("Sheet2").Select

'Start PivotTable below the last filled cell in Column 1
  lMaxRows = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).row
  StartPvt = sht.Range("A" & lMaxRows + 2).Address(ReferenceStyle:=xlR1C1) 

'Create Pivot Cache from Source Data
  Set pvtCache = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create( _
    SourceType:=xlDatabase, _
    SourceData:=SrcData)

'Create Pivot table from Pivot Cache
  Set pvt = pvtCache.CreatePivotTable( _
    TableDestination:=StartPvt, _
    tableName:=PivotTable)


End Sub
```

Comment: No chance to test atm but try this: `SrcData = E.Address(ReferenceStyle:=xlR1C1, External:=True)`. If you are dumping the *pivot table* in a different sheet, setting `External` argument will matter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As commented, try below first.

```
SrcData = E.Address(ReferenceStyle:=xlR1C1, External:=True)
```

in place of

```
SrcData = E.Address(ReferenceStyle:=xlR1C1)
```

If you are dumping the *pivot table* in a different sheet, explicitly setting [`External`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/range-address-property-excel) argument will matter since it will include the *sheet name* in the returned *address string* if set to `True`.

As per **MSDN**:

> True to return an external reference. False to return a local reference. The default value is False.

I based this on your comment that the commented line works.
I just have no way to check atm, but try on your end. HTH.

Comment: L42, you're a legend among men. Salty that two words would have saved me countless hours!